# How to make quill text editor readonly when you click the button in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, text-editor, quill

I have a quill text editor and as a default I want to set it as readonly and when the button is clicked, this should be true/false. So here is my component:

```
<template>
  <div ref="editor"></div>
</template>

<script>
import Quill from 'quill';
import 'quill/dist/quill.core.css';
import 'quill/dist/quill.bubble.css';
import 'quill/dist/quill.snow.css';

export default {
  props: {
    disabled: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    value: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    }
  },

  data() {
    return {
      editor: null,
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.editor = new Quill(this.$refs.editor, {
      modules: {
        toolbar: [
          [{ header: [1, 2, 3, 4, false] }],
          ['bold', 'italic', 'underline']
        ]
      },
      readOnly: this.disabled,
      theme: 'snow',
      formats: ['bold', 'underline', 'header', 'italic']
    });

    this.editor.root.innerHTML = this.value;

    this.editor.on('text-change', () => this.update());
  },

  methods: {
    update() {
      this.$emit('input', this.editor.getText() ? this.editor.root.innerHTML : '');
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I am sending this value as a prop to my component which is 'disabled' and when I click the button true becomes false and when I click again visa versa. So there is nothing wrong with that. Also when I do readOnly: true, or readOnly: false it works but with this way, readOnly: this.disabled it doesnt work.

I am using vue but I created a component based on quilljs directly.

The documentation I use is this one: https://quilljs.com/docs/configuration/#readonly

Comment: Did you tried to set the `readOnly` state on the Quill instance? Otherwise, you can always use a CSS hack with a z-index on top of it (dirty, but does the job pretty well IMO).

Answer (score 1):

I have a same problem and have a "[Vue warn]: Attempting to mutate prop "enable". Props are readonly." message when try to change props in component. You can pass "enable" or "disable" props to quill depends of button conditions and then reinit Quill component.

```
     <template>
  <div>
    <QuillEditor
        ref="myEditor"
        theme="snow"
        toolbar="full"
        :read-only=readOnly
        v-model:content="content" required contentType="html"
        :style='{width: width, height: height}'
    />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import { QuillEditor } from "@vueup/vue-quill";
import '@vueup/vue-quill/dist/vue-quill.snow.css'

export default {
  name: "MyQuillEditor",
  components: {
    QuillEditor,
  },
  props: ['width', 'height', 'showAvatar'],
  emits: ['resizeRowBar', 'saveInnerHtml', 'displayFontMenu'],
  data(){
    return {
      content: '',
      readOnly: false,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    collectHTML(){
      this.$data.readOnly = true;
      this.$refs.myEditor.reinit();
    }
  },

  mounted() {
  },
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

also you can use this.$refs.myEditor.getQuill().enable(true) to set active and this.$refs.myEditor.getQuill().enable(false) to unactivate write option.